# Why isn't my for loop printing like I would expect from my pseudocode?

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
int height = 24;

while (height > 23 || height <=0)
{
printf("How tall do you want the tower to be?\n");
height = GetInt();
}

for(int a = 0; a < height; a++)
{
    for(int c = a; c<=height; c++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(int b = height - a; b<=height; b++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

So, what I'm trying to do is have a tower that aligns with the left edge of the terminal window. For some reason though, this generates two extra spaces at the beginning of the "last" line (bottom of the tower). Even weirder, when I sit down with a pen and paper and manually run through the program, I'm showing that there should be on the first line, a number of spaces equal to "height" + 1, followed by one "#" then a new line, then a number of spaces equal to "height" followed by two "#", and so on. Why isn't my code evaluating like that, and what's with my two extra spaces? Sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: +1 for "I sit down with a pen and paper and manually run through the program", I encourage this.

Comment: Heh, thanks, I'm not really sure how else to figure a problem out sometime. It was the only way I could manage to figure out to do the "int b = height - a" bit. I'm a real junior at this, hopefully I won't have to be doing that forever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you print `height + 1` at the beginning of each line whereas you want to print `height-1` spaces.

Change your condition from:

```
for(int c = a; c<=height; c++)
```

to

```
for(int c = a; c<height-1; c++)
```

Comment: Ok, height - 2 in the C loop worked, thank you for that! But why... I don't see why it should have printed those two spaces at all. In fact, again, when I write it out, I show my original code as printing height + 1 spaces, and then height, and then height -1 in the first three lines. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not specific to last line alone. Easy to the see the problem is to input 1 for height.